# scheme, list of functions as parameter

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, tail-recursion

I'm trying to solve this problem. I was wondering if someone would help get started on it or give me some hints.

function called `apply-all` that, when given a list of functions and a number, will produce a list of the values of the functions when applied to the number.

For example,
`(apply-all (list sqrt square cube) 4)` => (2 16 64)

Thanks

OK. this is what I have so far,

```
(define (apply-all lst num)
  (apply-allaux lst num '()))

;; aux function
(define (apply-allaux lst num acc)
  (if (null? lst)
      acc
      (apply-allaux (cdr lst) num (cons (apply (car lst) num)))))
```

but when I run this

```
(apply-all '(positive?) 2)
```

it gives me this error

```
mcar: expects argument of type <mutable-pair>; given 2
```

Can anyone help me find the problem please?

Comment: Go look at the `map` function.

Answer (score 2):

Captain Pedantic says: have you taken a look at How To Design Programs (http://www.htdp.org) ?

You need to start by writing down examples--simpler ones than the one you have.  Also, write the result in a form in which it actually evaluates correctly.  (In your example, for instance, if you evaluate (2 16 64), you'll get an error.

Next, if you don't have experience developing functions over lists, you should really really be reading the first ten sections of HtDP; it's far better than a Stack Overflow answer can be.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok thank you. I've been programming for a couple of years now. But, I just started learning scheme. So, this is all new to me.

Comment: Disagree about "write the result in a form in which it actually evaluates correctly". I believe that since results are always data, never "code to be evaluated", answers should be written in "data mode" form, not "code mode" form. i.e., the result should be `(2 16 64)`, not `'(2 16 64)`. Yes, it means you can't just enter the data directly into the REPL without quoting first, but _learning the distinction between code and data mode_ is a crucial part of learning Scheme. IMHO.

Comment: @Chris: what about numbers & strings? Should their representations be different?

Comment: String and number literals look identical in code mode and data mode (though of course, in code mode, you're allowed to quote them too). So, there is no problem with writing them out as is. Really, what I'm trying to say is, I like to represent data in the form that `write` uses, so that `read` gets the correct result. Try these for size: `(call-with-input-string "(2 16 64)" read)` and `(call-with-input-string "'(2 16 64)" read)`. Only the first one yields the correct result.

Comment: True, but students don't use 'read' to make their test cases. When I write (my-call) => (list 3 4) and I want to make that into an executable test case, all I need to do is to wrap a pair of parens around the call and the expected answer. This is just the tip of a *much larger* iceberg; the whole notion of a reduction semantics depends on the notion that values and program terms live in the same space.  Using the 'write' syntax interposes an extra step.  In DrRacket, try using my Stepper on a simple expression like (cons (+ 3 (+ 4 5)) empty). Now think about using 'write' syntax in the output.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your attempt, I'll provide you some hints to get you through. :-)

- You don't need to use `apply` in your case. `apply` doesn't do what you think it does, notwithstanding that your assignment wants you to make a function called `apply-all`.
- `cons` takes two arguments.
- `'(positive?)` is a list that contains a *symbol* named `positive?`, not the `positive?` function. Your assignment used `(list ...)` for good reason. If you want something more compact than `list`, use quasiquotation: `` `(,positive?) ``.
- You should consider using `map`, like Marcin's comment suggests.
- If you can't use `map`, then remember that when you use the "iterate with accumulator" pattern, your results come out reversed. You must either reverse the input list or the result.

Here's my reference solution, which took me half a minute to write. :-) I'm hoping you can use it to fine-tune your existing version. (I'm comfortable with posting it because I'm certain your markers won't let you use `cut`, and if you can work out how to make my version acceptable to your markers, then you've already won.)

```
(define (apply-all fns . args)
  (map (cut apply <> args) fns))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the signature:

```
; apply-all : (listof (number -> number)), number -> (listof number)
```

Consider what apply-all should return:

- when the list is empty: an empty list (there are no functions to apply)
- when the list is not empty: use the first function on the number, combine the result with a natural recursion in a way that makes sense for lists (the list should shrink in the recursion).